# How to quickly compute 2^x?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I am reading a paper where question is: "How can you quickly compute 2 ^ X "?
Suggested answer in paper: "1 << X"

Off course this doesn't seems to be right answer, as I have tried things like

`2 ^ 9  = 11`

`1 << 9 = 512`

Wondering - can anyone think what logic I am missing here or author is really wrong here?

Comment: in some languages, '^' means to the power of. In others its XOR

Comment: 2 to the 9th power ***is*** 512. Do it on paper.

Comment: Also, the compiler is probably going to compute 2^x efficiently anyway, so you are no doubt worrying about a problem you don't have.

Comment: Close voters: I think this is a legitimate question. There is an ambiguity between the meaning of ^ as exponentiation or bitwise XOR that, if not understood, would make the shifting trick look totally wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting 2 ^ x to mean "two XORed with x," while the intent is probably 2<sup>x</sup>. In that case, `1 << x` is a fine way to compute 2<sup>x</sup>. It's unfortunate that when typing in plain text, ^ is often used to denote exponentiation, but in the context of C, C++, and Java, ^ represents the XOR operator. (It's also an easy trap for new C/C++/Java programmers!)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Downvoter: Can you explain what's wrong with this answer? I'm hoping to be as useful as possible and any input on how to do better would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

2<sup>9</sup> is 512.

So 1 << 9 does the correct thing.